# How can I read a known number of strings of unknown size from a .txt file and store each line in a line of a matrix (in C)?

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, fgets, fseek

Title is pretty self explanatory. I'm almost sure that the end result wouldn't be a matrix as each line would have a different number of columns, so it's more like a array of arrays of variable sizes. It would also be interesting to sort the fragments by size, biggest first. This is what I've tried so far:

```
int main() {
  char str[MAXLEN], **fragmentsList;
  int number_of_strings, i, max, k;
  printf("Enter .txt file name: ");
  scanf("%s", str);
  printf("How many strings does the file has? ");
  scanf("%d", &number_of_strings);
  FILE *arq;
  arq = fopen(str, "r");
  for (i = 0, max = 0; !feof(arq); i++) {
    while (fscanf("%c") != '\n') {
      max++;
    }
    if (max > k) {
      k = max;
    }
  }
  fclose(arq);
  fragmentsList = malloc(k * sizeof(char));
  *fragmentsList = malloc(number_of_strings * sizeof(char));
  arq = fopen(str, "r");
  for (i = 0; !feof(arq); i++) {
    fscanf(arq, "%s", fragmentList[i]);
  }
  for (i = 0; i < number_of_strings; i++) {
    printf("%s", fragmentList[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/), even when disguised as `for (i = 0; !feof(arq); i++)`. Your loop `while (fscanf("%c") != '\n')` is bogus: `fscanf()` will return 1 or EOF (in this context — in other contexts with a single conversion specification, it might return 0); neither of those is the same as `'\n'`. Your counting loop won't terminate. Can you use POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)?  If so, do so.  If not, consider writing an emulation of it and using that.

Comment: `fscanf("%c")` is wrong altogether. Maybe you mean `fscanf(file_handle, "%c", &ch)` Compile your program with max warning level, and fix all compiler warnings and errors.

Answer (score 0):

The reading an unknown number of lines from a file into memory in C is a basic necessity. There are a couple of way to approach it, but the standard practice is to:

- declare a `pointer to pointer to type` (`char**` for lines in a file) to allow you to collect and reference each line after read into memory;
- allocate some reasonably anticipated number of pointers to begin with to avoid repeated calls to `realloc` allocating pointers for each line individually (initially allocating `8, 16, 32, ..` all work fine);
- declare a variable to track the number of lines read, and increment for each line;
- read each line of the file into a buffer (POSIX `getline` works particularly well because it itself will dynamically allocate sufficient storage to handle any line length -- freeing you from reading with a fixed buffer and having to allocate for and accumulate partial-lines until the end of the line is reached)
- allocate storage for each line, copy the line to the new storage, and assign the beginning address to your next pointer, `strdup` does both for you, but since it allocates, make sure you validate it succeeds;
- when your index reaches your current number of allocated pointers, `realloc` more pointers (generally by doubling the number, or increasing the number by `3/2` -- the rate if increase isn't particularly important -- what is important is insuring you always have a valid pointer to assign the new block of memory holding your line to); and
- repeat until the file is completely read.

There are a few subtleties to be aware of when reallocating memory. First never `realloc` directly to to pointer being reallocated, e.g. do not do:

```
mypointer = realloc (mypointer, current_size * 2);
```

if `realloc` fails, it returns `NULL` and if you are assigning the return to your original pointer, you overwrite the address to your current data with `NULL` creating a memory leak. Instead, always use a temporary pointer and validate `realloc` succeeds before assigning the new block of memory to your original pointer, e.g.

```
    if (filled_pointers == allocated pointers) {
        void *tmp = realloc (mypointer, current_size * 2);

        if (tmp == NULL) {
            perror ("realloc-mypointer");
            break;      /* or use goto to jump out of your read loop,
                         * preserving access to your current data in
                         * the original pointer.
                         */
        }
        mypointer = tmp;
        current_size *= 2;
    }
```

Putting the pieces altogether in an example using `getline`, you can do something like the following. (note: the code expects the filename to read from as the 1st argument to your program, if no argument is given the program will read from `stdin` by default)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NPTR 8      /* initial number of pointers (must be > 0) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t ndx = 0,             /* line index */
        nptrs = NPTR,           /* initial number of pointers */
        n = 0;                  /* line alloc size (0, getline decides) */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;           /* return (no. of chars read by getline) */
    char *line = NULL,          /* buffer to read each line */
        **lines = NULL;         /* pointer to pointer to each line */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate/validate initial 'nptrs' pointers */
    if (!(lines = calloc (nptrs, sizeof *lines))) {
        perror ("calloc - lines");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line with POSIX getline */
    while ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, fp)) != -1) {
        if (nchr && line[nchr - 1] == '\n') /* check trailing '\n' */
            line[--nchr] = 0;               /* overwrite with nul-char */
        char *buf = strdup (line);          /* allocate/copy line */
        if (!buf) {             /* strdup allocates, so validate */
            perror ("strdup-line");
            break;
        }
        lines[ndx++] = buf;     /* assign start address for buf to lines */
        if (ndx == nptrs) {     /* if pointer limit reached, realloc */
            /* always realloc to temporary pointer, to validate success */
            void *tmp = realloc (lines, sizeof *lines * nptrs * 2);
            if (!tmp) {         /* if realloc fails, bail with lines intact */
                perror ("realloc - lines");
                break;          /* don't exit, lines holds current lines */
            }
            lines = tmp;        /* assign reallocted block to lines */
            /* zero all new memory (optional) */
            memset (lines + nptrs, 0, nptrs * sizeof *lines);
            nptrs *= 2;         /* increment number of allocated pointers */
        }
    }
    free (line);                    /* free memory allocated by getline */

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndx; i++) {
        printf ("line[%3zu] : %s\n", i, lines[i]);
        free (lines[i]);            /* free memory for each line */
    }
    free (lines);                   /* free pointers */

    return 0;
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. If you do not have `getline` or `strdup` available, let me know and I'm happy to help further with an implementation that will provide their behavior.